# Textbox with type="number" has blank Text

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I'm working on the mobile version of my website and have a few textboxes where I want the virtual keyboard to popup as numbers (phone, zip, etc). Some of these also have custom filters attached to them to validate what's entered. 
Because of the validators, I use asp:TextBox instead of a plain input. I then add type as an attribute in the codebehind

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox_Phone" runat="server" CssClass="inp-bl-lvl width95 l"
placeholder="Phone"></asp:TextBox>

SearchBox_Phone.Attributes.Add("type", "number");
```

I can get the correct value in js

```
$get('<%= this.SearchBox_Phone.ClientID %>').value;
```

but in the codebehind SearchBox_Phone.Text always returns blank. If I comment out the attribute addition I can get the correct value, but I really want to keep it as is.

Any idea how I can get the value, short of setting a hidden input in js (I'd like to avoid an extra value that needs setting/clearing)?

Comment: How this works may depend on which mobile browser(s) you are hoping to support. Which are you talking about here? Are you using the HTML5 doctype?

Comment: As many as possible :)

Comment: I don't get the problem you describe. With or without the attribute, I can read the value enetered on Postback with no problem

Comment: Also, you may not want to be *adding* the attribute. ASP.NET may already be providing `type="text"`; adding might be making it `type="text number"`, which wouldn't be valid. You may need to *replace* the `type` attribute.

Comment: I checked the source. IE and Chrome both render it as type="number". I'm not using HTML5 doctype. I'm using XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Comment: I think those alternative input types are HTML5 only.

Comment: I tried switching to HTML5. No change.